# Calculating the modulus from big exponential

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponential-function

I got this big number of exponential in my calculator.

```
1.37914152 * 10^18
```

I wanted to get rid of the 1 in front in order to calculate for the modulus, so I typed `- 1 * 10^18`

However, the result returned is `3.7914152 * 10^17`.

Just wondering is there any way to remove the 1 in front because I wanted to calculate for the modulus of

```
(1029*10832*1849*13108*3210*10868*2) mod 13667
```

Comment: Using the calculator of windows the answer seems to be $8472$. I confirmed it with [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1029*10832*1849*13108*3210*10868*2)+mod+13667). One question, why you want to quit the $1$ on your number???

Comment: Yeah the answer is 8472. Because I am calculating the modulus using normal scientific calculator whereby first, I need to divide with 13667, then I need to get rid of the whole number in front and lastly, multiply back with 13667 to get the answer. This works for small number but in this case, there is a 10^18 which I have no idea how to get rid of it :(

Comment: you can try to evaluate the modulus of the product of only two numbers, and after the product of these results.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? What should I type in the calculator?

Comment: first evaluate $(1029\cdot10832)\equiv a\bmod 13667$.The result will be $a$, now evaluate $(a\cdot 1849)\equiv b\bmod 13667$. The result will be $b$. Repeat to end. That is you must write `1029*10832 mod 13667 * 1849 mod 13667 * 13108 mod 13667...`

Comment: Thanks! that works like a charm! Could you please write it as answer so I can upvote the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a problem evaluating the modulus of some large numbers in some scientific calculators.

Then we can use the following property of the modular arithmetic (of natural numbers)

$$a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3\cdots a_n\equiv (...(((a_1\cdot a_2)\bmod c)\cdot a_3\bmod c)\cdots a_n\bmod c)\mod c$$

to setup a recursion easier to handle for these scientific calculators. Then in a calculator one must type sequentially

$$\boxed{a_1}\,\boxed{\times}\,\boxed{a_2}\,\boxed{\operatorname{mod}}\,\boxed{ c}\,\boxed{\times}\, \boxed{a_3}\, \boxed{\operatorname{mod}}\,\boxed{c}\,\boxed{\times}\,\boxed{a_4}\,\boxed{\operatorname{mod}}\,\boxed{ c}\, \cdots \boxed{\times}\, \boxed{a_n}\, \boxed{\operatorname{mod}}\,\boxed{ c}\, \boxed{=}$$

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm!